# Cartesian Product of PCollection with itself

Tags: java, python, apache-beam

Say I have a bounded PCollection p of type `KV<String, Integer>`. Assume p cannot fit in memory, and therefore cannot be a side input of a `DoFn`.

Example p:

```
("foo", 0)
("bar", 1)
("baz", 2)
```

How can I take the cartesian product of p and itself?

For example, `p x p` may look as follows:

```
("foo+foo", [("foo", 0), ("foo", 0)])
("foo+bar", [("foo", 0), ("bar", 1)])
("foo+baz", [("foo", 0), ("baz", 2)])
("bar+foo", [("bar", 1), ("foo", 0)])
("bar+bar", [("bar", 1), ("bar", 1)])
("bar+baz", [("bar", 1), ("baz", 2)])
("baz+foo", [("baz", 2), ("foo", 0)])
("baz+bar", [("baz", 2), ("bar", 1)])
("baz+baz", [("baz", 2), ("baz", 2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've surmised, the easiest way to do this would be to have a DoFn that processes your PCollection as a main and side input.

If this doesn't work because the PCollection is too large to fit into memory, you could partition it into N disjoint PCollections, pass it through each of those, and then flatten the result. For example, you could write something like

```
class CrossProduct(beam.PTransform):
  def expand(self, pcoll):
    N = 10
    parts = pcoll | beam.Partition(lambda element, n: hash(element) % n, N)
    cross_parts = [
        pcoll | str(ix) >> beam.FlatMap(
            lambda x, side: [(x, s) for s in side],
            beam.pvalue.AsIter(part))
        for ix, part in enumerate(parts)]
    return cross_parts | beam.Flatten()

output = input | CrossProduct()
```

Note, however, that unless the elements of your PCollection are particularly large, if the PCollection cannot fit into memory than its cross product may be prohibitively large to produce (and process).

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a solution using Python.

**In the first place, let's implement the algorithm and after that resolve the problems with the memory limitation**

```
import itertools

# Let's build a list with your pairs
collection_items = [("foo", 0), ("bar", 1), ("baz", 2)]

"""
A Python generator is a function that produces a sequence of results. 
It works by maintaining its local state, so that the function can resume again exactly where 
it left off when called subsequent times. Same generator can't be used twice.
I will explain a little later why I use generators
"""

collection_generator1 = (el for el in collection_items)  # Create the first generator
# For example; calling next(collection_generator1) => ("foo", 0); next(collection_generator1) => ("bar", 1),
# next(collection_generator1) => ("bar": 2)
collection_generator2 = (el for el in collection_items) # Create the second generator
cartesian_product = itertools.product(collection_generator1, collection_generator2) # Create the cartesian product

for pair in cartesian_product:
    first_el, second_el = pair
    str_pair1, val_pair1 = first_el
    str_pair2, val_pair2 = first_el

    name = "{str_pair1}+{str_pair2}".format(str_pair1=str_pair1, str_pair2=str_pair2)
    item = (name, [first_el, second_el]) # Compose the item
    print(item)

# OUTPUT

('foo+foo', [('foo', 0), ('foo', 0)])
('foo+foo', [('foo', 0), ('bar', 1)])
('foo+foo', [('foo', 0), ('baz', 2)])
('bar+bar', [('bar', 1), ('foo', 0)])
('bar+bar', [('bar', 1), ('bar', 1)])
('bar+bar', [('bar', 1), ('baz', 2)])
('baz+baz', [('baz', 2), ('foo', 0)])
('baz+baz', [('baz', 2), ('bar', 1)])
('baz+baz', [('baz', 2), ('baz', 2)])
```

**Now let's solve the problems with memory**

Since you have a lot of data, a good idea would be to store them in a file, writing a pair on each line (as in you example)
Now let's read the file ("input.txt") and create a generator with its data.

```
file_generator_1 = (line.strip() for line in open("input.txt"))
file_generator_2 = (line.strip() for line in open("input.txt").readlines())
```

Now, the only modification you have to do is to replace the variables name collection_generator1, collection_generator2 to file_generator_1, file_generator_2